# HTML <a> href that points to another <a> href

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a hidden `<a>` tag with some id. It renders by script, so I don't have access to it. And I have my own `<a>` which is visible to user. I want to when user clicks my own `<a>` it redirects him with same href which script rendered `<a>` has.

I can't use `<script>` tag or js script files.

```
<a href="/somegerantedhred" id="someId" style="display: none"></a>

<a href="somehow get same href"></a>
```

Comment: So you would need to select the element and set the href equal to the one that is not visible.

Comment: That's the problem. I cant use js

Comment: Well you are out of luck

Comment: Can you use an `onclick` attribute in your <a>?

Comment: Yes, I can use onclick attribute

Comment: " I cant use js" well onclick is JavaScript ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can add some javascript into your element instead of the script, you may have some luck using onclick. Then target the hidden link, get it's href value, and use it to change the window location:

```html
<a href="/somegerantedhred" id="someId" style="display: none"></a>

<a onclick="window.location.href = document.getElementById('someId').getAttribute('href')">Your button</a>
```

Comment: Whoa, I should have refreshed before I started typing my answer. Here, an upvote.

Comment: Hey thanks! Can you actually get the value using .href instead of getAttribute() ? It's cleaner, but doesn't appear to work for me.

Comment: Yes, it works here, under both browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Not having access to the tags or the js files makes it almost impossible, the best thing I could come up with would be to use CSS to unhide the generated anchor by using #someId {display:block!important} so that you can use that generated tag as your anchor, however, I am not sure if this generated tag already has a value, if it doesn't, then nothing will be displayed in the screen and without access to the DOM with JS, it is pretty hard to find a solution to this matter.

```css
#someId {display:block!important}
```

```html
<a href="/somegerantedhred" id="someId" style="display: none">The hidden content</a>

<a href="somehow get same href">Your content</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `onclick`, then just put this in your source:

```
<a href="/somegerantedhred" id="someId" style="display: none"></a>

<a onclick="window.location.href = document.getElementById('someId').href"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically click the hidden link:

```js
const hiddenLink = document.getElementById("someId");
const visibleLink = document.getElementById("visibleLinkId");

visibleLink.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  hiddenLink.click();
});
```

```html
<a href="/somegerantedhred" id="someId" style="display: none"></a>
<a href="#" id="visibleLinkId">Click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you must define an event handler or event listener for onClick in the button.
you can get the href of link like this:

```
document.getElementById("someId").href;
```

Also, you can change the link value to other href like this:

```
window.location.href= url;
```